# In elasticsearch, how does aggregation work on fields which are not stored

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

In the document that I index in elastic search i have 6 columns a,b,c,d,e,f. I have set _source=false for all, for columns a,b, I have set stored=true and for columns c,d,e,f, I have set stored=false.

As far as my understanding of aggregation in elasticsearch goes, aggregation works on the results of a query. But since I have set stored=true only for columns a,b, my search returns only columns a,b. What if I want to aggregate based on the column c. How will this aggregation work if I set stored=false. To make aggregation work on column c, will I have to set stored=true for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in order to do aggregations, the underlying values have to be saved somewhere on disk. These are not saved in the standard `stored` or `_source` fields of the mapping, but are instead saved in the `doc_values`.

This means that even if you set `stored=False` and `_source=False`, the values that you index may still nevertheless be saved if the doc values are saved. Doc values are automatically turned on for unanalyzed strings and numbers, but you can manually turn them off by setting `doc_values` to `False` in the mapping. If you turn them off, then aggregating on these fields will not work.

As a result of the above, you can retrieve the underlying values even if `stored=False` by querying the `doc_values` directly. Information on [how to do that is located here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-docvalue-fields.html).